# beginner SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a commission report that needs to include custom shipping rates if they are present in the order. Below I have two tables joined. If `OrderDetails.Custom` contains `'Freight'` or `'Overnight'` I need it to display `'OrderDetails.CustomPrice'`.

If `OrderDetails.Custom` does not contain `'Freight'` or `'Overnight'` I need it to leave `OrderDetails.CustomPrice` blank but still display all the other fields as long as the `WHERE` clause is met.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

```
SELECT Orders.OrderDate, Orders.OrderID,      Orders.PaymentAmount, 
       Orders.Shipping,  OrderDetails.Custom, OrderDetails.CustomPrice  
FROM Orders
  JOIN OrderDetails 
    ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '04/01/12 00:00:01' 
                    AND '04/30/12 11:59:59' 
  AND SalesRep_CustomerID = '21140';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a case statement :

```
SELECT Orders.OrderDate, Orders.OrderID, Orders.PaymentAmount, Orders.Shipping, 
CASE WHEN (OrderDetails.Custom = 'Freight' OR OrderDetails.Custom = 'Overnight') THEN OrderDetails.CustomPrice ELSE '' END AS  CustomPrice,
 OrderDetails.CustomPrice  
FROM Orders
JOIN OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '04/01/12 00:00:01' AND '04/30/12 11:59:59' and SalesRep_CustomerID = '21140';
```

Comment: This format: `'04/01/12 00:00:01'` for dates is an ad for trouble.

Comment: Yes, i didn't looked at the where clause .

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Now I just realized I am getting duplicates on Orders.OrderID for some reason. Is there any way to consolidate the output?

Answer (score 0):

Use case statement to get the value for the column "CustomPrice"